# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 119485: invalid start byte (while migrating sqlite3 to postgreSQL - djangocms)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-migration, django-cms

I have been trying to migrate the database of my djangocms project from the default sqlite3 to postgreSQL. But at the end of the process I got this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 119485: invalid start byte`.
I am not sure how to handle this issue as I have no experience in databases and most posts about this type of issues on the internet are not database-related from what I have seen.

What I did to reach this point:
I have created a local djangocms website with sqlite. To make the database migration, I have followed the procedure described [here](https://www.vphventures.com/how-to-migrate-your-django-project-from-sqlite-to-postgresql/): I dumped the database into a db.json file then created the new postgres database on pgAdmin. I modified the field DATABASES in my django settings.py, installed psycopg2 and ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` and then (in the Python shell) I ran:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all().delete()
```

before `python manage.py loaddata db.json`.

I also had to re-create a superuser which helped me to log into djangocms admin. But as expected my website was absent (and even the layout of djangocms was wrong).

Any help would be much appreciated!
Many thanks.

Here are the tracebacks:

```
(myWebsite) C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\project\website>python manage.py loaddata db.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\project\website\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\project\website\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 172, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File " C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 67, in Deserializer
    stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 119485: invalid start byte
```

What I did before and the prompt results:

```
(myWebsite) C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\project\website>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

(myWebsite) C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\project\website>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, aldryn_background_image, auth, bootstrap4_alerts, bootstrap4_badge, bootstrap4_card, bootstrap4_carousel, bootstrap4_collapse, bootstrap4_content, bootstrap4_grid, bootstrap4_jumbotron, bootstrap4_link, bootstrap4_listgroup, bootstrap4_media, bootstrap4_picture, bootstrap4_tabs, bootstrap4_utilities, cms, cmsplugin_soundcloud, contenttypes, djangocms_file, djangocms_googlemap, djangocms_icon, djangocms_link, djangocms_picture, djangocms_style, djangocms_text_ckeditor, djangocms_video, djangocms_vimeo, djangocms_wow, easy_thumbnails, filer, menus, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying filer.0001_initial... OK
  Applying filer.0002_auto_20150606_2003... OK
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cms.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cms.0002_auto_20140816_1918... OK
  Applying cms.0003_auto_20140926_2347... OK
  Applying cms.0004_auto_20140924_1038... OK
  Applying cms.0005_auto_20140924_1039... OK
  Applying cms.0006_auto_20140924_1110... OK
  Applying cms.0007_auto_20141028_1559... OK
  Applying cms.0008_auto_20150208_2149... OK
  Applying cms.0008_auto_20150121_0059... OK
  Applying cms.0009_merge... OK
  Applying cms.0010_migrate_use_structure... OK
  Applying cms.0011_auto_20150419_1006... OK
  Applying cms.0012_auto_20150607_2207... OK
  Applying cms.0013_urlconfrevision... OK
  Applying aldryn_background_image.0001_initial... OK
  Applying aldryn_background_image.0002_backgroundimage_background_attachment... OK
  Applying aldryn_background_image.0003_remove_backgroundimage_background_attachment... OK
  Applying aldryn_background_image.0004_backgroundimage_background_attachment... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying cms.0014_auto_20160404_1908... OK
  Applying cms.0015_auto_20160421_0000... OK
  Applying cms.0016_auto_20160608_1535... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_alerts.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_badge.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_card.0001_initial... OK
  Applying filer.0003_thumbnailoption... OK
  Applying filer.0004_auto_20160328_1434... OK
  Applying filer.0005_auto_20160623_1425... OK
  Applying filer.0006_auto_20160623_1627... OK
  Applying filer.0007_auto_20161016_1055... OK
  Applying filer.0008_auto_20171117_1313... OK
  Applying filer.0009_auto_20171220_1635... OK
  Applying filer.0010_auto_20180414_2058... OK
  Applying filer.0011_auto_20190418_0137... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_carousel.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_carousel.0002_bootstrap4carousel_carousel_aspect_ratio... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_carousel.0003_auto_20180610_1102... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_carousel.0004_auto_20190703_0831... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_collapse.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_content.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_content.0002_added_figure... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_grid.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_grid.0002_auto_20180709_0808... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_grid.0003_migrate_column_size... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_grid.0004_remove_bootstrap4gridcolumn_column_size... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_jumbotron.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_link.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_link.0002_add_icons... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_link.0003_icon_updates... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_link.0004_auto_20190703_0831... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_listgroup.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_media.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0002_auto_20151018_1927... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0003_migrate_to_filer... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0004_adapt_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0005_reset_null_values... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0006_remove_null_values... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0007_fix_alignment... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0008_picture_use_responsive_image... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_picture.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_picture.0002_bootstrap4picture_use_responsive_image... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_picture.0003_auto_20181212_1055... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_picture.0004_auto_20190703_0831... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_tabs.0001_initial... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_tabs.0002_auto_20180610_1106... OK
  Applying bootstrap4_utilities.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cms.0017_pagetype... OK
  Applying cms.0018_create_pagenode... OK
  Applying cms.0019_set_pagenode... OK
  Applying cms.0020_old_tree_cleanup... OK
  Applying cms.0021_auto_20180507_1432... OK
  Applying cms.0022_auto_20180620_1551... OK
  Applying cmsplugin_soundcloud.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cmsplugin_soundcloud.0002_auto_20210621_1556... OK
  Applying cmsplugin_soundcloud.0003_auto_20210621_1619... OK
  Applying cmsplugin_soundcloud.0004_auto_20210621_1639... OK
  Applying cmsplugin_soundcloud.0005_auto_20210621_1732... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0002_auto_20151202_1551... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0003_remove_related_name_for_cmsplugin_ptr... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0004_set_related_name_for_cmsplugin_ptr... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0005_auto_20160119_1534... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0006_migrate_to_filer... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0007_adapted_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0008_add_folder... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0009_fixed_null_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0010_removed_null_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_file.0011_auto_20181211_0357... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0002_auto_20160622_1031... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0003_auto_20160825_1829... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0004_adapted_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0005_create_nested_plugins... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0006_remove_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0007_reset_null_values... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0008_removed_null_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0009_googlemapmarker_icon... OK
  Applying djangocms_googlemap.0010_auto_20190718_1021... OK
  Applying djangocms_icon.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_icon.0002_auto_20190218_2017... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0002_auto_20140929_1705... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0003_auto_20150212_1310... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0004_auto_20150708_1133... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0005_auto_20151003_1710... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0006_remove_related_name_for_cmsplugin_ptr... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0007_set_related_name_for_cmsplugin_ptr... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0008_link_attributes... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0009_auto_20160705_1344... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0010_adapted_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0011_fixed_null_values... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0012_removed_null... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0013_fix_hostname... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0014_link_file_link... OK
  Applying djangocms_link.0015_auto_20190621_0407... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0009_auto_20181212_1003... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0010_auto_20190627_0432... OK
  Applying djangocms_picture.0011_auto_20190314_1536... OK
  Applying djangocms_style.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_style.0002_set_related_name_for_cmsplugin_ptr... OK
  Applying djangocms_style.0003_adapted_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_style.0004_use_positive_small_integer_field... OK
  Applying djangocms_style.0005_reset_null_values... OK
  Applying djangocms_style.0006_removed_null_fields... OK
  Applying djangocms_style.0007_style_template... OK
  Applying djangocms_text_ckeditor.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_text_ckeditor.0002_remove_related_name_for_cmsplugin_ptr... OK
  Applying djangocms_text_ckeditor.0003_set_related_name_for_cmsplugin_ptr... OK
  Applying djangocms_text_ckeditor.0004_auto_20160706_1339... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0002_set_related_name_for_cmsplugin_ptr... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0003_field_adaptions... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0004_move_to_attributes... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0005_migrate_to_filer... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0006_field_adaptions... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0007_create_nested_plugin... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0008_reset_null_values... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0009_removed_null_values... OK
  Applying djangocms_video.0010_videoplayer_parameters... OK
  Applying djangocms_vimeo.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_vimeo.0002_update_related_name... OK
  Applying djangocms_wow.0001_initial... OK
  Applying djangocms_wow.0002_auto_20210611_1217... OK
  Applying djangocms_wow.0003_auto_20210621_1750... OK
  Applying easy_thumbnails.0001_initial... OK
  Applying easy_thumbnails.0002_thumbnaildimensions... OK
  Applying filer.0012_file_mime_type... OK
  Applying menus.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... OK

(myWebsite) C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\project\website>python manage.py shell
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> ContentType.objects.all().delete()
(376, {'auth.Permission': 300, 'contenttypes.ContentType': 76})
```

And when I log in the website:

```
(myWebsite) C:\Users\...\vEnv\myWebsite\project\website>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 25, 2021 - 17:21:21
Django version 3.1.11, using settings 'regSite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[25/Aug/2021 17:21:33] "GET /en/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13923
[25/Aug/2021 17:21:33] "GET /static/cms/css/3.8.0/cms.base.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[25/Aug/2021 17:21:33] "GET /static/cms/js/dist/3.8.0/bundle.toolbar.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[25/Aug/2021 17:21:33] "GET /en/static/cms/css/3.8.0/cms.base.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[25/Aug/2021 17:21:33] "GET /en/static/cms/js/dist/3.8.0/bundle.toolbar.min.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[25/Aug/2021 17:21:33] "GET /static/cms/css/3.8.0/cms.welcome.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[25/Aug/2021 17:21:34] "GET /en/static/cms/css/3.8.0/cms.welcome.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[25/Aug/2021 17:21:34] "GET /static/cms/js/dist/3.8.0/bundle.toolbar.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[25/Aug/2021 17:21:34] "GET /en/static/cms/js/dist/3.8.0/bundle.toolbar.min.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Comment: A quick google suggests opening db.json in a text editor, checking the file is and saving the file as UTF-8

Comment: It looks like your sqlite database contains some (very large) entries that have non-ASCII characters that are not in UTF-8.  Given that you're on Windows, that's not surprising; it's probably CP1252.  I don't know whether the DJango converter has a way to specify the character set, but there are lots of ways to convert a file's character set, including online sites.

Comment: Thanks guys, you seem to have pinpointed the issue. I opened the db in Notepad and used save as with UTF-8 encoding. The website is there again but the layout is messed up... I have to investigate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ian Shelvington and Tim Roberts, I opened the db in Notepad and used save as with UTF-8 encoding. Then I ran `python manage.py loaddata db.json` again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://www.solution-hub.com/Blog_description/4/) where you can find steps to change the database. It's about SQLite to Mysql but I think the process will be very much similar.

****Note:** Don't forget to take a backup of your data before doing anything to your DB.**

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly what I did and which led to that situation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is custom command:

proj\proj\management\commands\db_load_portable_data.py

django 3.2, python 3.10

```
import json

from django.core.management import BaseCommand, call_command
from django.conf import settings


def fix_dumpdata_encoding(fixture_path: str):
    with open(fixture_path) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    with open(fixture_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **opts):
        home_dir = settings.BASE_DIR
        dump_path = 'proj/fixtures/tmp'
        app_model_set = (
            'auth.User',
            'auth.Permission',
            'auth.Group',
        )
        for app_model in app_model_set:
            output_path = f'{home_dir}/{dump_path}/{app_model}.json'
            print(output_path)
            call_command('dumpdata', app_model,
                         indent=4, natural_foreign=True, natural_primary=True, output=output_path)
            fix_dumpdata_encoding(output_path)
            print()
        print(f'Dump done, path: {dump_path}')
```